# HTML форма не работает в APPLE устройствах

Tags: javascript, html, yii2

Есть HTML форма. На другом браузерах кнопка submit работает. Но в apple устройствах не работает, в консоле нет ошибок. Для точности сайт - telegruz.uz там есть форма регистрации, вот и это форма не работает.

```html
<form id="mysignup-form" action="/site/signup" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf-frontend" value="Tmk4bW0uSG48G309NGgGIgofTVxdSgUZGjxKHxxZCQMBWHpcPkABIA==">            <div style="display: none">
        <div class="form-group field-avatarfile">

            <input type="hidden" name="File[file]" value=""><input type="file" id="avatarfile" class="hidden" name="File[file]">

            <div class="help-block"></div>
        </div>            </div>
    <div class="modal-body editTable">
        <div class="rows-col">
            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group center">
                <div class="avatar"><img id="u-avatar" src="/files/default/avatar.png"></div>
                <div id="files" class="files"></div>
                <span id="avatarupload" class="btn btn-warning fileinput-button sm">Загрузить фото                </span>
                <div id="progress" class="progress" style="display: none">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="row-item">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 orange">Логин<span class="required">*</span></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control sm" name="SignupForm[username]" id="username" data-enabled="0">
                        <label class="hint-message"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-item">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 orange">Пароль<span class="required">*</span></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control sm" id="password" name="SignupForm[password]" data-enabled="0">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-item">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 orange">Повторите пароль<span class="required">*</span></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control sm" id="password_repeat" name="SignupForm[password_repeat]" data-enabled="0">
                        <label class="hint-message"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="rows-col">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="row-item">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 orange">Имя<span class="required">*</span></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control sm not-empty" name="SignupForm[first_name]" id="first_name" data-enabled="0" data-name="Имя">
                        <label class="hint-message"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-item">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 orange">Город<span class="required">*</span></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="SignupForm[city_id]">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control sm not-empty" name="SignupForm[city]" id="city" onkeyup="return getCities2($(this))" autocomplete="off" data-enabled="0" data-name="Город">
                        <label class="hint-message"></label>
                        <div class="places-list" style="display: none;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-item">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 orange">Телефон<span class="required">*</span></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <input type="tel" maxlength="13" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 &amp;&amp; event.charCode <= 57 || event.charCode == 43" class="form-control sm not-empty" name="SignupForm[phone1]" data-enabled="0" data-name="Телефон">
                        <label class="hint-message"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-item">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 orange">Деятельность</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="select-group form-group">
                            <i class="icon menu-icon orange"></i>
                            <div class="hidden_select_container"><div class="hidden_select_container"><div class="hidden_select_container"><select name="SignupForm[activity]" class="simpleselected" size="2">
                                            <option value="1">Частное лицо</option>
                                            <option value="2">Экспедитор</option>
                                            <option value="5">Экспедитор-Перевозчик</option>
                                            <option value="3">Диспетчер</option>
                                            <option value="4">Перевозчик</option>
                                            <option value="6">Грузовладелец</option>
                                            <option value="7">Грузовладелец-Перевозчик</option>
                                        </select></div><div class="simpleselect"><div class="placeholder">Частное лицо</div><div class="options" style="height: auto; overflow-y: visible;"><div class="option">Частное лицо</div><div class="option">Экспедитор</div><div class="option">Экспедитор-Перевозчик</div><div class="option">Диспетчер</div><div class="option">Перевозчик</div><div class="option">Грузовладелец</div><div class="option">Грузовладелец-Перевозчик</div></div></div></div><div class="simpleselect"><div class="placeholder">Частное лицо</div><div class="options" style="height: auto; overflow-y: visible;"><div class="option">Частное лицо</div><div class="option">Экспедитор</div><div class="option">Экспедитор-Перевозчик</div><div class="option">Диспетчер</div><div class="option">Перевозчик</div><div class="option">Грузовладелец</div><div class="option">Грузовладелец-Перевозчик</div></div></div></div><div class="simpleselect"><div class="placeholder">Частное лицо</div><div class="options" style="height: auto; overflow-y: visible;"><div class="option">Частное лицо</div><div class="option">Экспедитор</div><div class="option">Экспедитор-Перевозчик</div><div class="option">Диспетчер</div><div class="option">Перевозчик</div><div class="option">Грузовладелец</div><div class="option">Грузовладелец-Перевозчик</div></div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Зарегистрировать</button>
            <div class="information">
                Перед регистрации пользователя  убедитесь в правильности введенных данных. Подробнее читать <a href="/site/conditions" class="orange">Условия пользования</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что не работает?

Comment: В форме когда нажимается кнопка submit ничего не происходит.

Comment: Если код в вопросе точно такой же как у тебя, то проблема не воспроизвелась. Как ты определил, что ничего не происходит?

Comment: Ну открыл браузер. Зашел на сайт. Заполнил форму и нажал кнопку. Это только в apple устройствах не работает, а в остальных нормально работает.

Comment: с ipod все отлично сработало.

Comment: Вы это с сайта telegruz.uz проверили?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59014/discussion-between-grundy-and-davron-rahimov).